# Get MatSlider to work with ionic 5 (vertical slider)

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-material

I tried many hours to get a vertical slider (like ion-range) to work. Seems like the best option is to go with the material slider.

I had a lot of issues getting it to work on mobile devices and at least the imports are not trivial so I'd like to share what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First install hammer JS

```
npm install hammerjs 
npm install @types/hammerjs
```

Then you need to import hammerjs separately

```
//in app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { GestureConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'hammerjs';
```

Then add it to the imports and also the the providers

```
//in app.module.ts
imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), NgxSliderModule, AppRoutingModule, HammerModule
    ],

providers: [
        { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: GestureConfig }
    ],
```

Then on your page module, import the slider

```
//in myComponent.module.ts
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';

...
imports: [
    MatSliderModule,
  ],
```

Now you are ready to use it :)